# how to add if condition in <td> tag in php

Tags: php, html

i want to add if condition in  tag in a table.

code:

```
 for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
    {
    $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $lit=$result['PMID'];
    $lit1=$result['Gene'];
        if($color==1){  
      echo "<tr bgcolor = '#DCDCDC'>";
      echo "<td align = center>" . $result['Gene'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td align = center>" . $result['Observation'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td align=center><a href='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/$lit' target='_blank'>" . $result['PMID'] . "</a></td>";
       *echo "<td align=center><a href='./gene_$lit1.html' target='_blank'>" . $result['Tissue_expression'] . "</a></td>";*

      //echo "<td>" . $result['gene_symbol'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
```

this is the code i am using

```
echo "<td align=center><a href='./gene_$lit1.html' target='_blank'>" . $result['Tissue_expression'] . "</a></td>";
```

above is the line is where i want to add if condition i.e. if $lit1 == NULL; echo "No expression found";

kindly help me. thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Where does `$lit` go in that line? In the `href`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional expression (e.g. `a ? trueCond : falseCond`):

```
echo "<td align=center>".
     (($lit != NULL) ?
         ("<a href='./gene_$lit1.html' target='_blank'>" . $result['Tissue_expression'] . "</a>") : 
         "No expression found"
     )."</td>";
```

Although it would be probably more readable if you would just split your echo statement into several lines and use a regular if statement.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `<td align=center>`

Comment: @TomFenech `align=center` comes from the question itself so I'm repeating it to provide him with an answer to his specific question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if`and `else` command for this

```
echo "<td align='center'>";
   if($lit) 
      echo "<a href='./gene_$lit1.html' target='_blank'>" . $result['Tissue_expression'] . "</a>";
   else  
      echo "No expression found";
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: I'd definitely prefer this approach too. You can use conditional expression, but its uglier.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `<td align=center>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a few things missing here.

Don't use `bgcolor` or `align` attributes, they're very old-fashioned. Use CSS. I've included it in a `<style>` tag but this should really be in a separate stylesheet.

It looks like you're obtaining the same `$result` every time you go through the loop, so I moved it outside. If that's not the case, obviously you need to move it back in.

Don't needlessly concatenate strings containing HTML. Just write HTML! If you want to `echo` some PHP along the way, then you can do so using [short echo](http://www.php.net/echo) `<?=$variable?>`, which is supported since PHP 5.4.0. Otherwise, `<?php echo $variable ?>` is still better.

Here's the code with all those changes made. I am using [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to determine whether `$lit1` is set and is not `NULL`:

```
<style>
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    tr {
        background-color: #DCDCDC;
    }
</style>

<?php
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++) {  
    $lit=$result['PMID'];
    $lit1=$result['Gene'];
    if($color == 1) { ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?=$result['Gene']?></td>
        <td><?=$result['Observation']?></td>
        <td><a href='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/<?=$lit?> target='_blank'><?=$result['PMID']?></a></td>
        <td>
            <?php if (isset($lit1)) { ?>
                <a href='./gene_<?=$lit1?>.html' target='_blank'><?=$result['Tissue_expression']?></a>
            <?php } else echo "No expression found"; ?>                
        </td>
        <?php }
```

Comment: hello tom,, thnx 4 suggesting such basic things

Comment: but its still not working as i want,, it is giving the page if it is getting with gene name, but showing error if gene name is not available. i.e. not printing the else message

Comment: This is probably because `$lit1` is set but `$result['Tissue_expression']` isn't. What is the error message?

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9

Comment: actualy here i am trying to search the file name with gene name, nd there is no file for some genes, that may be the problem.

Comment: A 404 error is nothing to do with this code. It means you're trying to access a URL that cannot be found. As the message suggests, you need to check that the link is correct and change it if necessary.